# Angular Date pipe with Timezone doesn't convert properly

Tags: angular, date, time, timezone, pipe

I'm passing a UTC datetime to the angular app and I want to display the time in a different timezone. This is what the returned date looks like on Postman:

```
"2021-07-21T09:15:00" - this is in UTC.
```

I want to convert this to a different timezone (determined at runtime) so I tried something like below, but it always show the same UTC value.

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      {{ dataItem.returnedTime | date: 'hh:mm a' : 'IST' }}
    </ng-template>
```

I tried the following as well:

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      {{ dataItem.returnedTime | date: 'shortTime' : 'IST' }}
    </ng-template>

 <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      {{ dataItem.returnedTime | date: 'hh:mm a' : '+530' }}
    </ng-template>
```

I expect this to show 2:45PM, instead it show 9:15AM.

What's wrong here?A

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that value is in UTC, it should have a `Z` on the end, as in `"2021-07-21T09:15:00Z"`.

Per the [ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse):

> ... When the UTC offset representation is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and **date-time forms are interpreted as a local time**.

Append a `Z` to the input string, either on your back end or when you receive it, and it should work fine.

Comment: Also, I'm not entirely certain that `"IST"` will be valid.  There are three different time zones with that abbreviation (India, Israel, Ireland).  That time zone feature of Angular is buggy anyway.  See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20225

Comment: Thanks! this was really helpful. You are correct, 'IST' doesnt give the correct conversion, I had to use the actual offset.